# Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://controller:5000/v3

Tags: 18.04, openstack

When trying to setup a controller node for openstack USSURI version. I'm asked to setup glance service as VM images management sub-service.

As of requirement : article (under ubuntu 18.04) :

1. I created a file named : admin-openrc.sh , under location : /usr/share/keystone , with content :

   ```
   export OS_USERNAME=admin
   export OS_PASSWORD=ADMIN_PASS
   export OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin
   export OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=Default export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
   export OS_AUTH_URL=http://controller:5000/v3
   export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
   ```

   where ADMIN_PASS is customized
2. Type cmd : `source ./admin-openrc.sh`
3. Then, create glance user with cmd : `openstack user create --domain default --password-prompt glance`

As output, I receive error message :

```
Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://controller:5000/v3. Attempting to parse version from URL.
Unable to establish connection to http://controller:5000/v3/auth/tokens: HTTPConnectionPool(host='controller', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/auth/tokens (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fa20bba02b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))
```

Would anybody advise please ? I completed previously all steps : NTP install, openstack packages download, SQL install, RabbitMQ install, Memcached install, Etcd install, Keystone install (USSURI version)

It seems to be authentication issue maybe or something else ?